# MySql Trigger INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not recognising columns

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables in a Mysql database: "stock_pricing" and "DATA_IMPORT"

columns in first table:  `STOCK_ID`, `DATE`, `LAST_CLOSE_DOM_CURR`
columns in second table: `STOCK_ID`, `DATE`, `ADJ_CLOSE`

The first table has an index on stock_id and date together. These have been defined as UNIQUE.
The second table has no index at all.

The second table has incoming data. On this table there is a BEFORE INSERT trigger that inserts incoming data into the first table.

If upon the insert trigger the combination of STOCK_ID and DATE violates the UNIQUE index of the first table, the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE part of the trigger is fired.

I have tried every combination I can think of, but the trigger does not recognise my column names, any thoughts? Many thanks.

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO stock_pricing (`STOCK_ID`, `DATE`, `LAST_CLOSE_DOM_CURR`) 
VALUES (DATA_IMPORT.STOCK_ID, DATA_IMPORT.DATE, DATA_IMPORT.ADJ_CLOSE)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
stock_pricing.STOCK_ID= DATA_IMPORT.STOCK_ID, stock_pricing.DATE= DATA_IMPORT.DATE, stock_pricing.LAST_CLOSE_DOM_CURR= DATA_IMPORT.ADJ_CLOSE;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing a table called `data_import` with no `from` clause.  This is fixed using `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO stock_pricing (`STOCK_ID`, `DATE`, `LAST_CLOSE_DOM_CURR`) 
    SELECT DATA_IMPORT.STOCK_ID, DATA_IMPORT.DATE, DATA_IMPORT.ADJ_CLOSE
    FROM DATA_IMPORT
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    stock_pricing.STOCK_ID= DATA_IMPORT.STOCK_ID, stock_pricing.DATE= DATA_IMPORT.DATE, stock_pricing.LAST_CLOSE_DOM_CURR= DATA_IMPORT.ADJ_CLOSE;
```

A more typical way of writing such a query is:

```
INSERT INTO stock_pricing (`STOCK_ID`, `DATE`, `LAST_CLOSE_DOM_CURR`) 
    SELECT di.STOCK_ID, di.DATE, di.ADJ_CLOSE
    FROM DATA_IMPORT di
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE STOCK_ID = VALUES(STOCK_ID),
                            DATE = VALUES(DATE), 
                            LAST_CLOSE_DOM_CURR = VALUES(LAST_CLOSE_DOM_CURR);
```

For `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to work, you need a unique index or primary key.  I assume you have these.

Finally, this code looks a bit strange for a trigger, because there are no references to `NEW` or `OLD`.  If you are still having trouble with the trigger, then ask *another* question and include the full code for the trigger.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Yes unique key is in there. My posted code is my full code and I took my lead from the Mqsql reference manual. I've tried your code but still unfortunately still get the same response: SQL Error (1054) Unknown column 'ADJ_CLOSE' in field list'.

Comment: @user3237164 . . . That should be `VALUES(LAST_CLOSE_DOM_CURR)`, the name of the column in the new table.

Comment: DATA_IMPORT.ADJ_CLOSE value is entered into stock_pricing.LAST_CLOSE_DOM_CURR, how can LAST_CLOSE_DOM_CURR = VALUES(LAST_CLOSE_DOM_CURR) work? Why wouldn't it be: LAST_CLOSE_DOM_CURR = VALUES(di.ADJ_CLOSE)?? Which incidentally does not work either. I'm very confused. Is it because at the time of firing the On duplicate part of the trigger, the di.ADJ_CLOSE value has already been passed to the LAST_CLOSE_DOM_CURR value?